# Javascript: Toggle z-indexed DIVs Visibility in IE6/7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-8

I am attempting to create a simple popover effect using jquery, similar to a popover in iOS.  The code works perfectly fine in ff, safari, chrome, and ie9, but the popover does not appear in ie6-8.

I'm using jquery 1.5.1, as well as html5shiv so that I can use html5 tags:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script defer src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="effects.js"></script>
```

The relevant javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').live('click', function($e) {
        $e.preventDefault();
        $('#popover').fadeToggle('fast');

        if ($('#button').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#button').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#button').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

The relevant CSS code for the popover is:

```
#popover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 5000000;
}
```

IE is correctly adding and removing classes when I click on the button.  Also, when I change the CSS of the popover to be display: block, then the popover correctly shows up when the page loads in IE.  However, for some reason IE seems to be unable to toggle the div's display.  I've tried putting the javascript code at the bottom of the page, adding type="text/javascript", changing fadeToggle to simply show, using getElementById to change the css of popover, and I think every other solution I've seen on here related to IE and jquery, click(), live(), and/or z-index.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try without using .live()?  As in just `$("#button").click(function(){...})`

Comment: Yes, I've tried simplifying the javascript function all the way down to:

    $('#button').click(function() { $('#popover').show(); });

with no success

Comment: maybe html5shiv.js has something to do with it since it only loads for the browsers your code doesn't work in.  Did you try removing that?

Comment: Also try removing the `$e.preventDefault();` bit and add `return false;` at the end of the method instead.

Comment: I was reluctant to change all my code and tags, although I just did try that and removed html5shiv.js and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried removing display:none from css and put it on #popover element? I once fixed a similar problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions that I have used in the past is to add the element on the page at the click event. For example, in your case:

$('#button').live('click', function($e) {
  $e.preventDefault();
  $(this).after('');
...
});

Comment: For some reason this solution doesn't seem to be working in this case.

Comment: The idea is that you add the popover when the click event happens. SO the DOM does not contain the #popover, once the click event is called you can add it within the DOM. You may have to let it know where exactly you want it placed and the use of $(this) may not work for you. I can show you examples if you need them.

Comment: The concept makes sense, it just isn't working for me in ie8 (only one I tested).  It was working in firefox and safari though.  I'm going to try to put up a sample on a server later and post the link to see if maybe somebody can see someone outside of the posted code that I'm missing.

Comment: OK, I've put up some example code: [example.html](http://202.112.50.209/example/example.html).  This works perfectly in modern browsers including ie9, but not at all in ie6-8.  Bonus points if you can figure out why ie7 breaks the button or how to get the toggle working.

Comment: Junquan, why are you using 'live'. This button does not seem to be created dynamically which defeats the purpose of 'live'. Why not use 'click' or 'bind'? If you are set on using 'live', have you considered 'livequery' (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)? cheers, Kia

Comment: @Kia I'm using just 'click' in my live code, the example uses live because at the time I had some suggestions that live would be more compatible with ie. But, as I mentioned above, neither live nor click is working.  I did try livequery as well, without success.

I put a link up to some example code because from everything I'm reading and seeing, this code **should** be working, so I'm wondering if there isn't some issue elsewhere that is breaking it.